# Binding TCP port fails in native executable (android)

Tags: android, tcp, android-ndk, video-streaming, rtmp

I'm trying to use [rtmpgw](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/rtmpgw.8.html) to set up a stream on a local port, to be accessed using a videoview or some other video player. I have the native executable set up and it's working, however when I test it with the command

```
rtmpgw --sport 8080
```

it returns the following error:

```
HTTP-RTMP Stream Gateway v2.4
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu; license: GPL

ERROR: startStreaming, TCP bind failed for port number: 8080
ERROR: Failed to start HTTP server, exiting!
```

This happens on any port I've tried. Without the `--sport` argument it tries port 80 and fails. From my understanding, non-privileged/non-root users can't bind ports lower than 1024 in unix. Since this is a virtual machine is it different? Wouldn't the native executable / static binary be executed outside the virtual machine?

Code:

```
File rtmp = new File(getFilesDir() + "/rtmpgw");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./" + rtmp.getName(), "--sport", "8080");
pb.directory(getFilesDir());
Process stream = pb.start();
```

Comment: Native executables aren't really encouraged on Android.  That said, they can presently work.  One question would be what userid they are running under - it needs to be one which has network permission. However, most ways you could get a shell (adb, or a terminal app on the device) would presumably have network permission.  You might see if you can track down an Android build of the netcat executable and try that (iirc it's included in AOSP sources), as perhaps the program you are using now is reporting a misleading error message for some other reason.  Or port 8080 is busy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. It turns out being above port 1024 isn't the only requirement. It needs to fall in the [ephemeral port range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). To get the ephemeral port range, I executed the command

```
root@android:/ # cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
32768   61000
```

I'm not certain how consistent that range is across all android devices, but my native executable successfully starts when given a port within the ephemeral range.

Comment: I got an adb shell while the device was plugged into a Windows computer via USB.

Answer (score 1):

Your native app runs outside of VM, but still it is limited by Android permissions mechanism. As Chris pointed above, you could try it first from adb shell, which to a large extent compensates these limitations. If your server fails there, try some other port numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, good to know even though it's running outside the VM it's still limited by the app's permissions. So it sounds like the user that runs the code is dynamically created by the OS depending on the app permissions.